# What are some examples of incomplete nonextendible manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

A connected Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is said to be *extendible* if it is isometric
to a proper open subset of a larger connected Riemannian manifold (this is the definition given in Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds*). I was able to show that a complete Riemannian manifold is nonextendible. I would like to find an example of incomplete Riemannian manifold which is not extendible. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) such manifolds exist, but no reference is given.

> What are some (relatively simple) examples of connected incomplete nonextendible Riemannian manifolds ?

I tried looking at the case of the real numbers $\mathbf{R}$, without great success. More specifically I tried to find conditions on a metric on $\mathbf{R}$ to be extendible. Suppose that there is a metric $g$ on $\mathbf{R}$ and an isometric embedding $\varphi:(\mathbf{R},g)\hookrightarrow (M,g_0)$ with $M$ a connected 1-manifold and with $\varphi(\mathbf{R})\subsetneq M$. For example we can look at the case $M=\mathbf{R}$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{R})=(-\infty,0)$ with $\varphi$ increasing. Writte $g_0 = f(x)dx^2,~f>0$. Then, $\varphi$ bieng an isometry, we get

$$g = \underbrace{f\circ\varphi(x)\varphi^\prime(x)^2}_{h(x):=}dx^2.$$

Now $\varphi$ is strictly increasing and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \varphi(x)=0$ so there is a sequence $(x_n)_n\in\mathbf R^\mathbf N$ converging to $+\infty$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi^\prime(x_n)=0.$$

Since $f$ in bounded near $0$, we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)=0.$$

Therefore if we want to construct nonextendible metric $g=h(x)dx^2$ on $\mathbf R$ "by hand", we might want to assume $h$ is bounded bellow by a positive constant $\varepsilon>0$ (so that there is no sequence $(x_n)_n\in\mathbf R^\mathbf N$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} \vert x_n\vert = +\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)=0$). However I am pretty sure that these metrics are all complete (even if I don't have an actual proof of this fact), so I don't think I am gonna find an example in this way.

In dimension two, the only incomplete manifolds I can think of are punctured surfaces, but these are all extendible.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never thought about this before. What if you take the punctured plane, but make a non-radially symmetric metric as you come in to the origin? What if you have something like $r^2\,d\theta^2 + f(r,\theta)\,dr^2$, where $f(r,\theta)$ looks like $1$ near $\theta=0$ but then looks like $1/r$ near $\theta=\pi$?

Comment: @TedShifrin from Wofsey's answer I guess this works with $f(r,\theta)=2$.

Comment: I was aiming for the radial distance to be bounded in some directions and to be unbounded in others. This would give neither a cone nor a cylinder, but a blend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a simple example, take the surface $C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=z^2,z>0\}$ with the metric inherited from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$.  This is a cone without its vertex.  To complete it as a metric space, you would just need to add in the vertex, but this completion is not a Riemannian manifold since it is not smooth at the vertex.

Comment: Agh! Too easy! :)

Comment: Nice answer, but can you explain why you need the vertex for it to be a metric space?

Comment: You don't need the vertex to have a metric space, but you need it to have a *complete* metric space.

Answer (score 5):

Although this has been answered a while ago, I cannot resist describing one of my favorite examples, which is related to the comment of @TedShifrin.

Start with the ordinary Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ and then lift it to the universal cover. The resulting space is isometric to $(0,\infty) \times (-\infty,+\infty)$ with coordinates $r \in (0,\infty)$, $\theta \in (-\infty,+\infty)$, equipped with the metric $dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2$. A nonconvergent sequence $(r_n,\theta_n)$ in this space is Cauchy if and only if $r_n \to 0$: indeed the infimal path length (*aka* distance) from $(r_1,\theta_1)$ to $(r_2,\theta_2)$ is $\le r_1 + r_2$. For similar reasons, all nonconvergent Cauchy sequences are equivalent. Thus the completion is obtained by adding one point.

Comment: Yes, of course. ;) This is actually a disguised variant of a surface I  put as an exercise in my differential geometry text, but had never thought about prior. It's a cone with countably many leaves — more officially, a cone over the usual helix — given parametrically by $\mathbf x(u,v) = (v\cos u,v\sin u,uv)$ with $v>0$.

Comment: This example is actually “cleaner” than Eric’s answer.  Because the arbitrary isometries fails to be a proper open set is more obvious.